# Resize UITableview of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using two searchbar on top of eachother in my layout like so :

[image: double search bar]

Both search bar have a UISearchDisplayController that display a suggestions table.

My problem is, the top search bar's display controller draws its UITable over the bottom searchbar like so :

[image: draw over bottom bar]

I tried to move the bottom table down in the uisearchdisplaydelegate like so:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller      
didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
float yOffset = 50.0f;
tableView.frame =  CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,tableView.frame.origin.y + yOffset,tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);                                  
}
```

But even though the method get called at the right time, it doesnt seem to do anything.

Id basically like the top searchbar suggestion table to be located at the same position as the bottom search bar suggestion table

I'm using storyboards and autolayout latest xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 7, you can just set the y origin to the yOffset. If you print out the frame of the table view in

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

you'll notice that the origin.y is at 0,0. In iOS 6 however, it's different. If you're planning on supporting both versions you'll need a check in there. Try setting the origin.y in the delegate method mentioned above.